# How to rewrite url with query string in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect-url, 301-redirect

I want to rewrite url like:

https://www.test.com/custom-parent-cat/sub-cat/10-12-14-17-19.html?cat=101

to

https://www.test.com/custom-parent-cat/sub-cat.html

Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263293/magento-2-product-attribute-filter-url-rewrite

Comment: This should be done at the server level in nginx or apache configs. If you are using nginx i would recommend using map if you want to make redirect from old urls to new url : https://www.tendenci.com/help-files/nginx-redirect-maps/ . If you want a regex then with nginx you can use a regex to redirect to sub-cat.html when the param cat is present in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 reads parameters in the following format: somepage/param/param_value/

It ignores the question mark. In your situation you have 2 options to go:

1. Manage this by using the rewrite rules of the webserver.

For more information on this, please check:

Nginx - https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Apache - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

2. Write your custom router for processing URLs

Please see my example on how to do this there: Configure front name in admin panel