# Change url filter in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4

Me again.

When I filter in a category in Magento, it show a page like `www.mymagento.com/mycategory?cat=3`

Exist a way to replace the ID for the name? for example `www.mymagento.com/mycategory?cat=mysubcategory`

or in a better way `www.mymagento.com/mycategory/mysubcategory`

Thanks!

Comment: follow this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263293/magento-2-product-attribute-filter-url-rewrite